# how to handle salesforce hover in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

Facing a problem with the hover(pop up) on Salesforce web-page while identifying it through selenium web driver.[image]

Comment: How about adding more details of the problem... like are u having trouble identifying the element to hover... or the pop-up is not getting displayed when the mouse is moved over the element. Adding page source would help in trouble shooting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Below code help to resolve above problem.

  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[text()='Show Me Later']"));
  JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);